# Is it correct to start a sentence with "Pas ici pour..."?

Tags: grammaire

I want to know if this sentence is grammatically correct in French:

> Pas ici pour être spectateur.

I need something in the lines of the English:
*"Not here to prove."
"Not here to be right."*

Can I start a sentence with "pas ici pour.."?

I am limited with words, so I cannot use the long "Je ne suis pas venu pour..."

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

> [Pas là pour rigoler](https://youtu.be/v2pHu9ggso4).

*Pas ici pour être spectateur* isn't the best phrasing though, maybe *Pas là comme spectateur* or *Pas là pour regarder*.

Here is a graphic showing that *là* is more common than *ici* after *je suis* (unlike after *je suis venu*):

[image]

Comment: what's the meaning of "la" ? Is it "there" or "here" ?

Would this "je suis pas ici pour etre spectateur." be better?

Thanks a mil!!

Comment: *Je ne suis pas ici pour...* and *je ne suis pas là pour...* both translate to *I'm not here for...* but *pas là* is a little bit more usual. That's the opposite with *venir* with which the usual collocation would be *ici*. NGram added to my reply.

Comment: Thank you guys!!!!